# Find In Path context

Tags: intellij-idea, path, find

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 on Linux.

In the menu there Edit - Find - Find In Path. In the search dialog there is a combobox Context with values anywhere, in comments, ...

Is it possible to define my own contexts and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add your own context, but you can add a [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scope.html):

> To create and edit scopes, use the Scopes page of the Settings dialog. Scopes are defined in the following modes:
>
> Manually, by specifying file masks according to the scope language syntax in the Pattern text box.
> By selecting files and folders and clicking the buttons Include, Include Recursively, Exclude, and Exclude Recursively. Based on the inclusion/exclusion, IntelliJ IDEA creates an expression and displays it in the Pattern.
> Refer to the section Configuring Scopes and File Colors.

So basically a scope defines, which files belong to it (e.g. all files in src/test).

After you have defined your own scope, you can use it in `Find in Path` by changing the `scope` to `custom` and selecting your scope. This will perform a search only for files defined in your scope. You can additionally use a context to further narrow down your search.

Here's a configuration and result for the example you have provided in the comment:

[image]

Comment: OK, I found out how to use them. But the main problem still exists. the main problem is that using context anywhere does not include results returned by context "in string literals"

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify the use of scopes. The context `anywhere` does exactly this - it searches in the whole file content (comments, strings, code - everything), but only for files defined in your scope.

Comment: I understand that, but, for example:  

* I have a file A.java that has a method "public void inDb()" and another method that has "String b = "DB(";"  
* now when context "anywhere" is selected I only get back the method  
* when context "in string literals" is selected I only get back String definition  

Why don't I get back (method and String definition) on "anywhere"?

Comment: Your example works correctly for me. Makre sure, to check off `case sensitive`and `whole words only`. Also make sure to open both subtrees in the results panel (results are categorized by default). See my screenshot for the right configuration and result.

Comment: Ahhh, it works all along. False alarm. :( Your first screenshot helped me realize I don't look at all results, only under "Undefined occurance".